# How to select a whole number in a string if the position can change?

Tags: python, string, indexing, numbers, bots

Right now I am on creating a Discord bot for my own server. I`m trying to give it a random number feature, so in the discord chat you can type

> !rng 0
>   6

And then the Bot will return a random number between 0 and 6.

This works with this code

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!rng'):
        highest = int(message.content[-1])
        lowest = int(message.content[-3])
        random = str(randint(lowest, highest))
        await message.channel.send("I choose " + random)
```

However, as soon as the chosen numbers are bigger than 9 (more than 1 digit) it starts to fail because my indexing is only designed to work with 1 digit numbers. Is there any way on how I could make it work with bigger numbers? So you can say a random number between 172 and 18361, or whatever. Some way to let it pick out the whole number.

I had the idea to do some for loops, that check if the next string letter is a number, and append that to a number so I get the whole number in the end, but I bet there is some better way with less code and hassling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could use regular expressions:

```
import re
text = '!rng 0 6'
results = re.findall('\d+', text)
print(results)
```

will print `['0', '6']` you can combind it with `map(int,results)` to get (a generator of) ints

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to separate the numbers:

```
lowest, highest = map(int, message.split()[1:])
```

Comment: Nevermind the comment i just did. The message missed .content to work as string. It works now. Thanks alot, that map function is awesome

Comment: @Trackster `split` is a method strings have, in your case it should be `message.content.split()`

Comment: Yea, i realized that the .content was missing. It works now, thats great. Thx